# page layout for function description

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I write an SDK manual in which I would like describe function using the following layout, but I have a carriage return I don't want.

```
Parameters    * unsigned int
              * string

Return Value  0 means ....
              1 means .......


Remarks       blablabla ....
```

But for now I have an issue with the `\item` command used in the **Parameters** section. I defined:

```
\newenvironment{parTitleLeft}[1]
{~\\
\par\setlength{\leftskip}{3cm}\noindent\ignorespaces\hspace{-3cm}\makebox[3cm][l]{{#1}}\ignorespaces}
{\par}

\newenvironment{parTitleLeftItems}[1]
{{#1}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3cm]\ignorespaces}
{\end{itemize}}
```

And use those command with:

```
\begin{parTitleLeftItems}{Parameters}
\item blabla ...
\end{parTitleLeftItems}
```

I get:

```
   Parameters      THE FIRST ITEM SHOULD BE HERE 
                   * unsigned int
                   * string
```

How can I remove that additional line break ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a MWE: I guess you are using the `enumitem` package from `leftmargin` but who knows?

Comment: The vertical space occurs because the `itemize` environment starts a new "paragraph". If you are not worried about pagebreaks being forbidden between items you could use minipages. Better yet I would suggest you use a list environment for the `Param` `Return Value` `Remarks` list and then nest an itemize for the details.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical space you are seeing derives from the fact that the text before the itemize is on its own paragraph (since the itemize starts a new block).

A solution based on nested lists:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{docFunction}{description}{1}
\setlist[docFunction,1]{labelwidth=3cm,labelsep=0cm,leftmargin=3cm}

\newenvironment{parTitleLeftItems}[1]
{\item[#1]\begin{itemize}[labelsep=1ex]}
{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{docFunction}
\begin{parTitleLeftItems}{Parameters}
\item blabla
\item blabla
\item blabla
\end{parTitleLeftItems}
\begin{parTitleLeftItems}{Return Value}
\item[0] means
\item[1] means
\end{parTitleLeftItems}
\end{docFunction}

\end{document}
```

I assumed you are already using the `enumitem` package from your use of `leftmargin`.

The idea is that the "Parameters" and "Return Value" tags are indeed labels of an outer list (a `description` in this case) and as such will be typeset on the same line as the contents of the item, which in turn is an itemize here.

Instead of setting the parameters for the spacing manually or with a custom macro I make use of the `\newlist` command of `enumitem`.
If you are using an outdated version of `enumitem` and `\newlist` is not available you can replace the two lines defining `docFunction` with

```
\newenvironment{docFunction}
  {\begin{description}[labelwidth=3cm,labelsep=0cm,le‌​ftmargin=3cm]}
  {\end{description}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on my Windows PC, but not on the Centos Distrib my compagny use to build!  \newlist is report as an " Undefined control sequence."

Comment: maybe you have an old version of `enumitem`. You can have the same result by defining a new environment `\newenvironment{docFunction}{\begin{description}[labelwidth=3cm,labelsep=0cm,leftmargin=3cm]}{\end{description}}` or you could download the new version from ctan and put the files in your working directory